# Searching for web based profilers for measuring the performance of web based application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a web application that runs quite slow. Hitting the request from one JSP page to another takes a long time. I have to measure it performance and find out the classes taking up most time. In other words I have to make an end to end analysis. Please advise me about free profiler tools to measure the performance of a web based application.

The one I have found is http://visualvm.java.net/features.html, but I want free profilers for Java EE web based applications.

And also guys what about jprofiler  http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/whatsnew72.html I think it is also a good tool but not a free one.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a developer machine?

Comment: @home yeah very much..!!

Comment: So use your IDE profiling tools... or just add some kind of stop watch.

Answer (score 1):

My one and only recommendation for your requirements would be JavaMelody: http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/. It's great, free and gives a clear overview of which methods take up most of the time or even which SQL statements.

Comment: @TheStijn..Thanks a lot..Please tell me I have downloaded it jar also but it is not executable , Please tell me how to use it ,I have downloaded the jar already..!!

Comment: You deploy it with your war and then you can see the statistics results on a separate (e.g. http://localhost:8080/monitoring). More info: http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#Setup

Answer (score 0):

You can try HttpWatch, they have a free version. This is useful for end-to-end measurement. You can combine this with Selenium to measure scenarios.

http://www.httpwatch.com/

java melody gives a different perspective from the server/thread/connection stand point

http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/

JMeter helps you to simulate loads

http://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Eclipse`, try [**Eclipse TPTP (Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform Project)**](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/).

TPTP addresses the entire test and performance life cycle, **from early testing to production application monitoring**, including test editing and execution, monitoring, tracing and profiling, and log analysis capabilities. The platform supports a broad spectrum of computing systems including embedded, standalone, enterprise, and high-performance and will continue to expand support to encompass the widest possible range of systems.

Comment: @ArjanTijms: Yes. You need to perform few additional steps such as installing `Agent Controller` but once done, it's nice.